# Interpolation layer not moving by time slider using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, inverse-distance-weighted, timeslider

I have  temporal point data and time slider works well for points , but while I use IDW interpolation the interpolation raster is fixed and does not change by time slider.

Is there any way to move this raster by  time slider?

I'm using ArcMap  10.6.

[image]

According to the picture above, as I move time slider my attributed with time points change, but the interpolation raster is fixed, while I want that to change as time change.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying the raster cell values represent some quantity of time?

Comment: Suppose we have a set of points, each of which has a value, and we can interpolate between these points to reach the value. Now the data is timed and I want to have an animation of the interpolation raster changes.

Comment: Still not clear,  your points are you interpolating some value such as temperature for a set of points that are also attributed with time? Edit your question, and show us exactly what it is you have.

Comment: yes I have a set of points that are also attributed with time and the problem is interpolation raster does not move as points move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single raster does not support the time slider, look at [this page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/time/how-time-is-supported-in-spatial-data.htm) on the help file which discusses which datasets support time.

If you had many interpolated rasters you could try stacking them up into a [NetCDF](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/time/how-time-is-supported-in-spatial-data.htm#GUID-381DCF5A-EA88-4401-B34D-3CCA32D33563) format and enable time that way? This is something I have never done and not sure is possible? May be someone else can add to this answer?